# How to replace multiple texts in a file in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am automating a process using c#. My script would look like below,

```
 UPDATE   Table
 SET   param_val = REPLACE(param_val,'Proxy430/','Proxy440/')
 WHERE   param_key = 'PROXY_URL'; 

 UPDATE   Table 
 SET   param_val = REPLACE (param_val, '.420/', '.430/')
 WHERE   param_val LIKE '%.420/%';
```

For every month, we will upgrade the version like `44` in place of `43` and `43` in place of `42` and run this script. To automate, i've written C# code and used below code

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
text.Replace(oldvale, newvalue);
File.WriteAllText(filepath, text);
```

But, issue is it can replace one word only. How to replace two texts in a file. In my case, `Proxy430` should be replaced as `Proxy440` and `Proxy440` into `Proxy450` in single shot.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call replace in the right order you can accomplish two replacements on a single line.

```
string TestString = @"UPDATE   Table
SET param_val = REPLACE(param_val, 'Proxy430/', 'Proxy440/')
WHERE param_key = 'PROXY_URL';

UPDATE Table
SET param_val = REPLACE(param_val, '.420/', '.430/')
WHERE param_val LIKE '%.420/%'; ";

const string oldFrom = "Proxy430";
const string oldTo = "Proxy440";
const string newFrom = "Proxy440";
const string newTo = "Proxy450";

string result = TestString.Replace(newFrom, newTo).Replace(oldFrom, oldTo);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The output is:

```
UPDATE   Table
 SET param_val = REPLACE(param_val, 'Proxy440/', 'Proxy450/')
 WHERE param_key = 'PROXY_URL';

UPDATE Table
 SET param_val = REPLACE(param_val, '.420/', '.430/')
 WHERE param_val LIKE '%.420/%';
```

Comment: Thank you. It suits me and i've developed the same

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't assign the `return value` of Replace method. Replace doesn't modify `this` string it returns replaced string.

Change it like this:

```
text = text.Replace(oldvale, newvalue);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cvCxDG).

Comment: OP wrote that he is able to replace one word only with his code. From this I assume that the lack of assignment is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If the things are really sequential numerically, you can do something like this:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
for (int i=lowestVersion; i < highestVersion; i++)
{
     var oldValue = i.ToString() + "0";
     var newValue = (i+1).ToString() + "0";
     text.Replace(oldValue , newvalue);
}
File.WriteAllText(filepath, text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom method for this.

```
private void MultipleReplace(string text, string[] oldValues, string[] newValues)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < old.Length; i++)
    {
        text = text.replace(oldValues[i], newValues[i]);
    }
}
```

You need to consider the order of replacements, because once you replace `Proxy430` by `Proxy440`, you can no longer replace `Proxy440` by `Proxy450`, because that'll also replace the values updated in the previous iteration.

Example:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
string[] oldValues = { "Proxy440", "Proxy430" };
string [] newValues = { "Proxy450", "Proxy440" };
MultipleReplace(text, oldValues, newValues);
File.WriteAllText(filepath, text);
```